# Sticky instead of fixed Footer

Tags: css

I have a full-width `#body-container` and a fixed width `.bg-container` on top of that. Both are minimum 100% of the available height.

So my footer is again on top of that - at the moment. But I want it to be after the `#body-container`.

So my question is: How do I need to adjust my setup to get the footer sticky?

[As pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMvezN?editors=110)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#body-container {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.bg-container {
  width: 920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.pseudo-content{
  background: yellow;
  height: 1000px;
}

footer{
  background: green;
  height: 50px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="body-container">
  
  <div class="bg-container">
    <div class="pseudo-content">content</div>
  </div>
  
</div>


<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you need that your footer always be displayed?

Then, just add the following styles to your `footer`:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
```

Complete:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
    height: 50px;
```

}

Comment: No, this is why I've asked for "sticky instead of fixed", because that is the current behavior ;)

Comment: Footer always bottom, no matter the height:

http://jsfiddle.net/loruit/bftfhkyz/